# Seeking general advice: is there a better way to echo dynamic HTML than heredoc? (smarty / php / html)

Tags: php, html, smarty, heredoc

**Project:** To create dynamic multi page form that populates the fields in different ways depending on various situations.

**Context:** Using CMSMS and Smarty tags to insert PHP into the requried pages. Each single page of the form is being built using a single smarty

**Current Method:** Using smarty tags, I am writing large chunks of HTML echoed in heredoc notation. When I reach a part of the form that needs to be dynamically genearted (such as a drop down menu) I escape the heredoc, write the PHP (using standard echo functions to generate the HTML required for that form element) then return to heredoc for more chunks of HTML.

**Suspicion:** this is inelegant, messy, tedious and just feels wrong.

**Request:** Any idea of a better way of doing this?

EDIT: An example of a chunk of my current setup, here you can see an initial chunk of static HTML is echoed - (the start of the form, and the first question) then a drop down menu which requires dynamic generation depending on the data that exists in the SESSION variables. After this, the heredoc resumes and echos more static HTML:

```
echo <<<EOD
<form id="myform" method="post" action="?page=2">
<div class="myform">

<div class="formfield">
    <div class="question"><label for="sv_01">Question?</label> <input type="text" name="sv_01" value="$sv_01" size="10" maxlength="10" /></div>
        <div class="subquestion"><label for="sv_02">What Year?</label>
EOD;
                echo '<select  name="sv_02">';   
                $vars = array(
                '-Year' => 'Year',
                '-2012' => '2012', 
                '-2011' => '2011', 
                '-2010' => '2010', 
                '-2009' => '2009', 
                '-2008' => '2008', 
                '-2007' => '2007', 
                '-2006' => '2006', 
                '-2005' => '2005', 
                'Pre 2005' => 'Pre 2005', 
                );

                foreach($vars as $val => $name){
                    if($_SESSION['sv_02'] == $val){
                        echo '<option value="' . substr($val, 0, 1) . '" selected>' . $name . '</option>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<option value="' . substr($val, 0, 1) . '">' . $name . '</option>';
                    }
                }

                echo '</select></div>';
echo <<<EOD

    <div class="question"><br /> <label for="sv_04">Another question</label> <input type="text" name="sv_04" value="$sv_04" size="10" maxlength="10" />%</div>
        <div class="subquestion"><label for="sv_07">When was the data collected?</label> 
EOD;
                echo '<select  name="sv_07">';   
                $vars = array(
                '-Month' => 'Month',
                '-January' => 'January', 
                '-February' => 'February', 
                '-March' => 'March', 
                '-April' => 'April', 
                '-May' => 'May', 
                '-June' => 'June', 
                '-July' => 'July', 
                '-August' => 'August', 
                '-September' => 'September', 
                '-October' => 'October', 
                '-November' => 'November', 
                '-December' => 'December', 
                );

                foreach($vars as $val => $name){
                    if($_SESSION['sv_07'] == $val){
                        echo '<option value="' . substr($val, 0, 1) . '" selected>' . $name . '</option>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<option value="' . substr($val, 0, 1) . '">' . $name . '</option>';
                    }
                }

                echo '</select><select  name="sv_08">';

                $vars = array(
                '-Year' => 'Year',
                '-2012' => '2012', 
                '-2011' => '2011', 
                '-2010' => '2010', 
                '-2009' => '2009', 
                '-2008' => '2008', 
                '-2007' => '2007', 
                '-2006' => '2006', 
                '-2005' => '2005', 
                'Pre 2005' => 'Pre 2005', 
                );

                foreach($vars as $val => $name){
                    if($_SESSION['sv_08'] == $val){
                        echo '<option value="' . substr($val, 0, 1) . '" selected>' . $name . '</option>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<option value="' . substr($val, 0, 1) . '">' . $name . '</option>';
                    }
                }

                echo '</select></div>'; 

echo<<<EOD          


<div class="continue"><input type="submit" value="Continue" /></div>
</div>

</div>
</form>
EOD;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opposed to standard HTML+PHP? This works fine with templating tools too.

```
public function render() {
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?= $this->title ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is my awesome page</h1>

        <p>Choose from a menu.</p>
        <?php $this->renderMenu() ?>

        <p>Or enter your details:</p>
        <?php $this->renderForm() ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
}
```

If this isn't what you're getting at, show some code.

Comment: I've added an example of my code - the problem I face is that as far as I can tell within CMSMS you use user defined smarty tags to insert php into your pages. Within these user defined tags the <?php ?> syntax isn't recognised, so I can't escape out of and back into as easily.

Comment: I haven't used Smarty specifically, but you could create custom tags to build those menus and (I think) still be able to pass in the session variable (selected value).

Comment: BTW, do those dropdowns work? The `<option>` values created using `substr($val, 0, 1)` will all be `"-"` except for the last entry which gets `"P"`.

Comment: oh yes - I updated that code, was using a slightly older version, mistakenly initially set it to 0,1 when it should be just 1 - but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From your description of the code (why aren't you showing any?) I suspect a code somewhat similar to

```
<?php

$someVariable = "Hello < World";
echo <<<FOO
 <!-- chunk of HTML -->
 {$someVariable}
 <!-- chunk of HTML -->
FOO;

// simulating some function calls
echo str_repeat('A', 10);
```

If this is the case, then let me tell you that this is *not* Smarty. That's simply heredoc (and quoted variables).

---

If you've separated the above code from things like database access, I can't see anything *messy* about it. Messy would be mixing output generation with business logic.

But to me (being a [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net))-developer, this does indeed look inelegant and feels wrong. But that's probably a subjective thing - being used to the "elegance" of a template solution like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net), [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [phpTAL](http://phptal.org/), [Mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php#mustachephp) (and five billion other engines).

These libraries do a great deal more than simply generating HTML. They take care of escaping values (`is 4 < 5?` is invalid HTML). They help you structuring and organizing your templates. They do caching for you. They've seen internationalization. and. a. whole. lot. more.

Comment: Apologies for not showing code intially, thought it might be painful to pick through! 

I'm completely new to smarty, so sorry if I'm using the term incorrectly. THe situation is this: CMSMS uses user defined smarty tags to insert code into pages. You can enter HTML directly, but to insert PHP you need to bnuild a smarty tag.

As far as I can tell within these smarty tags I can't use <?php ... ?> to escape my php and switch in and out of it easily, so I'm having to use chunks of echo.

For one thing it's clunky, for another it doesn't currently work.

Comment: Template solutions - I don't really understand what these are but will do some reading about them - do you know if they would be compatible with a CMS in the way I am using it, or would you advocate a complete bail on current methods if it meant access to an elegant template engine?

Comment: As far as I know CMSMS comes bundled with Smarty. Just have a look at their tutorials on how to integrate it?

Comment: Adding PHP to Smarty is best done through [plugins](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.tpl)